# How to prevent TWICImage from clipping CR2 in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, bitmap

I have Canon RAW images (.CR2) with resolution 5760x3840. When I read them to a Delphi (Embarcadero RAD Studio XE5 Update 2) application using Loadfromfile, I get bitmaps with a resolution 5760x3240. However, the bitmap represented by my CR2 images is 5760x3840 (CorelPhotopaint shows the full resolution in the same computer). As far as I understand, the TWICImage clips some lines from top and/or bottom of the bitmap to force it to 16x9 format. I am using a Microsoft camera codec downloaded a few days ago (6.3.9721.0). Is there a way to prevent clipping, and are the missing 600 lines 300 from top, 300 from bottom?